# Charting Library for Android Studio

Tags: android, charts

I am having a school Project where I have to make an android app (For 9th-10th Grade students), which will make a `Line Chart`

```
 A straight Infinite line(Not a line segment) on XY-Caartesian Coordinate system
```

by taking two points as input and plotting it on the graph in realtime.

So I need some suggestion on which `Android Charting Library` I should get started with, Below are some features the library should have:

- Quick Loading
- Seamless Zooming and Panning
- Real-time Ploting
- Good User Interface (As its for children)
- Customisable Chart(views) for Better UI delivery.

PS:Currently, I am trying to complete this project in `Android Studio using JAVA` and have tried
`MPAndroid Chart` so far
, if you have some other better libraries in different frameworks/tech-stack please mention it.